# Setting “AuthenticatedUsers” as user UserRights

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

I'm trying to set custom protection to a file with permission to any authenticated user.
I couldn't find any related info in the MIP SDK documentation.
Any comment/suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same request from a customer, and I'm checking if the following solution is feasible for them.

You could define a label in management portal, configure the protection for Any Authenticated Users, and then set it with SDKs.

**EDIT**

I implemented and tested this solution and it works as expected.
Be aware that it will take some time before the label is usable in code, after it is created in the portal. In this time-frame an error is thrown by SDKs.